# "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ." angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

this is my file authService.js :

```
angular.module('authService', [])

.factory('Auth', function($http, $q, AuthToken){


    var authFactory = {};


    authFactory.login = function(username, password) {

        return $http.post('/api/login', {
            username: username,
            password: password
        })
        .success(function(data) {
            AuthToken.setToken(data.token);
            return data;
        })
    }

    authFactory.logout = function() {

        AuthToken.setToken();
    }
    authFactory.isLoggedIn = function() {

        if(AuthToken.getToken())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    authFactory.getUser = function() {

        if(AuthToken.getToken())
            return $http.get('/api/me');
        else
            return $q.reject({ message: "Utilisateur n'a pas de token"});
    }

    return authFactory;
});


.factory('AuthToken', function($window) { *////// the problem is here //////*

    var authTokenFactory = {};

    authTokenFactory.getToken = function() {

        return $window.localStorage.getItem('token');
    }

    authTokenFactory.setToken = function(token) {

        if(token)
            $window.localStorage.setItem('token', token);
        else
            $window.localStorage.removeItem('token');
    }
    return authTokenFactory;
});


.factory('AuthInterceptor', function($q, $location, AuthToken){

    var interceptorFactory = {};

    interceptorFactory.request = function(config) {

        var token = AuthToken.getToken();

        if(token) {

            config.headers['x-access-token'] = token;
        }
        return config;
    };

    interceptorFactory.responseError = function(response) {

        if(response.status == 403)
            $location.path('/login');

        return $q.reject(response);
    }

    return interceptorFactory;
});
```

Comment: Is there anything before `.factory()`? [There should be a reference your application preceding it](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers#factory-recipe).

Comment: jonathan the problem is in this line when i run in the browser :/ help me please !!!

Comment: this is my file authService.js :

Comment: angular.module('authService', [])

.factory('Auth', function($http, $q, AuthToken){


 var authFactory = {};


 authFactory.login = function(username, password) {

  return $http.post('/api/login', {
   username: username,
   password: password
  })
  .success(function(data) {
   AuthToken.setToken(data.token);
   return data;
  })
 }

 authFactory.logout = function() {

  AuthToken.setToken();
 }
 authFactory.isLoggedIn = function() {

  if(AuthToken.getToken())
   return true;
  else
   return false;
 }

Comment: Please [edit your post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37190284/edit) to provide additional details. Comments aren't friendly to long code snippets.

Comment: ok this is my authService.js file :

Comment: If the error is related to an `$http` request, check the Network details in your browser's developer tools. Inspect the actual response text to ensure it is in the expected format. Verify that it is a single JSON *value* with nothing before or after.

Comment: angular.module('authService', [])

Comment: .factory('Auth', function($http, $q, AuthToken){

Comment: var authFactory = {};

Comment: authFactory.login = function(username, password) {

Comment: Sorry. Edit your question to include additional snippets. Don't post them in comments.

Comment: return $http.post('/api/login', {

Comment: With that, the problem is the `;` between each `.factory()`. They need to be removed. The way you're using `.factory()` only works as a single, long-running statement. Each `;` in the middle of it interrupts that.

Comment: jonathan thank you very much, it works perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the wrong semicolons, leaving the code like this:

```
angular.module('authService', [])

.factory('Auth', function($http, $q, AuthToken){
    var authFactory = {};

    authFactory.login = function(username, password) {
        return $http.post('/api/login', {
            username: username,
            password: password
        })
        .success(function(data) {
            AuthToken.setToken(data.token);
            return data;
        })
    }
    authFactory.logout = function() {
        AuthToken.setToken();
    }
    authFactory.isLoggedIn = function() {
        if(AuthToken.getToken())
        return true;
    else
        return false;
    }
    authFactory.getUser = function() {
        if(AuthToken.getToken())
            return $http.get('/api/me');
        else
            return $q.reject({ message: "Utilisateur n'a pas de token"});
    }

    return authFactory;
})
.factory('AuthToken', function($window) {
    var authTokenFactory = {};

    authTokenFactory.getToken = function() {
        return $window.localStorage.getItem('token');
    }

    authTokenFactory.setToken = function(token) {
        if(token)
            $window.localStorage.setItem('token', token);
        else
            $window.localStorage.removeItem('token');
    }
    return authTokenFactory;
})
.factory('AuthInterceptor', function($q, $location, AuthToken){

    var interceptorFactory = {};

    interceptorFactory.request = function(config) {
        var token = AuthToken.getToken();

        if(token) {
            config.headers['x-access-token'] = token;
        }
        return config;
    };

    interceptorFactory.responseError = function(response) {
        if(response.status == 403)
            $location.path('/login');
        return $q.reject(response);
    }

    return interceptorFactory;
});
```